# Modifying circled node to semi circled node and adding title below a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here's a code for the plot of the floor function. I wanted to make some modifications as:

1. changing the red circle to a red semicircle
2. there is two zeros lying on the axes, I want to delete one of them
3. finally I want to add a title below the plot. [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots,tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin = -3, xmax = 3, ymin = -3, ymax = 3]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \foreach \a in {-3,...,3}{
        \draw[blue] (\a, \a) -- (\a + 1, \a);
        \node [circle, draw, fill, line width = .5pt, color = blue, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 3pt] (ca) at (\a, \a) {};
        \node [circle, draw, fill=none, line width = .5pt, color = red, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 3pt] (ca) at (\a + 1, \a) {};
    } 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clip one half of the circle away, say `orig=false` to remove the `0` and put a simple node below the axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin = -3, xmax = 3, ymin = -3, ymax = 3]
    \tkzAxeX[orig=false]
    \tkzAxeY
    \foreach \a in {-3,...,3}{
        \draw[blue] (\a, \a) -- (\a + 1, \a);
        \node [circle, draw, fill, line width = .5pt, color = blue, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 3pt] (ca) at (\a, \a) {};
        \begin{scope}
        \clip ([xshift=-1em,yshift=-1em]\a + 1, \a) rectangle 
        ([yshift=1em]\a + 1, \a);
        \node [circle, draw, fill=none, line width = .5pt, color = red, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 3pt] (ca) at (\a + 1, \a) {};
        \end{scope}
    } 
    \node[below] at (0,-3.2) {title of the plot};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @marmot. These last days I’ve learned a lot from you.